# AND behaving like OR?

Tags: c++

I am evaluating an input and assigning its result (delimited by whitespace) to two variables.  Unfortunately, if user == "user" OR password == "pass" it seems to be breaking the loop!

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string username;
        string password;
        do {
            cout<<"Please enter the correct username and password.\n";
            cin>>username>>password;
            cin.ignore();
        } while (username != "user" && password != "pass");
        cout<<"username and password correct";
    }
```

Comment: && is AND, || is OR, ^ is XOR

Comment: You logic is flawed. You want || here for or. You want to repeat the loop if the username is wrong OR the password is wrong.

Comment: Boolean logic requires a bit of practice. It'll become second nature after you wrote your 1000th conditional statement.

Comment: Just hope the password doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: Let's hope they don't type in "user pass" as a username.

Comment: I was recently shown [The Codeless Code](http://thecodelesscode.com/contents). Ever since I can't help but picture suitable "corrections" for people who write input validation code like this.

Comment: @Domi That's the horrible thing, this is second nature.  It was just 3am and I was operating in moron-mode.

Comment: @KerrekSB Not to worry, not to worry, I perfectly understand there are issues, I'm just testing out the fundamentals of a new language. :P

Answer (score 8):

You really need an OR here:

```
while (username != "user" || password != "pass");
```

This in not a C++ issue, but rather, a Boolean logic one. See [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for example.

Comment: Umm...Good lord I'm going to bed.

Comment: Easiest reputation gain ever :-)

Comment: Haha you're welcome.  I'm actually a pretty good programmer, I just...I don't even know.

Answer (score 4):

To understand your mistake, it's time to see [De-Morgan's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) laws:

> "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"

So your code is like writing:

```
!(username == "user" || password == "pass")
```

Answer (score 3):

The `do..while` loop continues execution as long as the condition specified after the while keyword is true. You want the loop to continue as long as `username != "user"` *and* `password != "pass"`.

Let's now assume, that `username == "user"` and `password == "abc"`. Then first part of the condition will be met, but second won't. So your loop will end.

What you really want to do is to continue the loop as long `username != "user"` *or* `password != "pass"`. You can write it in the following way:

```
(...)
while (username != "user" || password != "pass");
```

Or, which is a little bit more clear:

```
while (!(username == "user" && pass == "pass"));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string username;
    string password;
    label:
    cout<<"Please enter the correct username and password.\n";
    cin>>username>>password;
    cin.ignore();
    if((username != "user") || (password != "pass"))
        goto label;
    cout<<"username and password correct";
}
```

Comment: Braces inside the condition are redundant, because && operator has less priority than != operator. The compiler will treat the expression the same way regardless if you put && operands in braces or not. And also this will yield the same result as the original OP's program (when you input "user" and "abc" the loop will end).

Comment: And If I could give another downvote, I would do so for using `goto`. `goto` is evil, because it breaks the logic of program flow (apart from fact, that it is counter-object oriented). So by using goto, you actually *decreased* readability of that program.

Comment: different example , and faster.

Comment: Faster in what terms?

Comment: # cat while.c 
int main() {
    while(1) {};
    return 0;
}

# cat forloop.c 
int main() {
    for (;;) { };
    return 0;
} # cat while.s 
    .file   "while.c"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
.L2:
    jmp .L2                    # this is the loop in both cases
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits

Comment: The amazing thing is that you got an up-vote *before* you fixed the logic.